Восстановление данных модульного деления

Мы получаем данные с прибора вида как на картинке. Видно, что это как остатки от модульного деления. Как восстановить в общем виде линейную функцию преобразования без разрывов?!


Это второй канал - частота ниже - период больше. В конце хвост не обращайте внимания, там должен быть переход на пилу опять, но из-за сглаживания так

Проверка величины скачка работает?

Не совсем понял комментарий. Это не скачки, это именно преобразование прибора от линейной функции на входе так. 19...25 шаг - это стабилизация параметра. Нужно именно получить линейную функцию. Есть второй канал, там также пила, но у нее период больше. Можно сыграть на биении  но как не могу понять.

Я, вероятно, понимаю, что это такое. Подобное поведение у графика фазы после преобразования Фурье (за счёт области значений atan2). Если между двумя точками есть изменение на почти 2Pi, а график фазы не бешено осциллирующий (обычно он довольно плавный), то к дальнейшим данным прибавляем 2Pi, если скачок был вниз, или -2*Pi , если был вверх (накопительно). В вашем случае величина добавки порядка 0.5

Почему вы думаете, что это остаток от деления? У вас график 0 пересекает, у чисел знак меняется туда-сюда, то плюс, то минус. Объясните: 1) Что это за график вообще, какова его природа, собственно? 2) Что вы хотите получить на выходе? И собственно, у вас всё же на входе числа, по которым вы рисуете графики, или прямо график только есть уже готовый на входе?
